# Retriving data sequentially from firebase after a certain amount of time everyday to make an android alarm app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to this. I have this alarm app project where I have to make a database which contains certain times of a day when my alarm will go on. I'm trying to use firebase for storing the times. Can anybody help me on how can I receive certain amount of data sequentially from my firebase database everyday?

Comment: Before you get voted down by someone i'll suggest you to edit your post and mention what you have tried so far and the links that you have studied etc. Something to show that you researched on this and are not able to accomplish because of such and such issue

Comment: @highhope too late

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom trigger like a cron job service like https://www.easycron.com/. You can trigger a cloud function through this or use the firebase cloud messaging to ask the device to sync data with this.